# Pickle EOF with Python3.8

Tags: pickle, python-3.8, eof, unexpectendoffile

I just recently changed my python version from 3.6 to 3.8 and I am struggling with my pickle file formats.
My code is writing an object to a pickle file '5lc_payload0.pickle'

```
with open('5lc_payload0.pickle', 'wb') as f: 
    pickle.dump(my_object, f)
```

and afterwards is uploading to s3 with simple upload operation.

```
def upload_files(self, items: List[Tuple[StorageUrl, PathLike]]):
    def upload_item(item):
        #(content_type, encoding) = mimetypes.guess_type(item[0].url)
        content_type='application/octet-stream'
        logger.info(f"Uploading single item {item[0]},{item[1]}, {content_type} ")
        self.upload_file(item[0], item[1], content_type)

    with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        submitted = [executor.submit(upload_item, item) for item in items]
        for f in futures.as_completed(submitted):
            f.result()
```

When downloading the file from s3 '5lc_payload0_s3.pickle' and trying to read it with

```
aws s3 cp s3://temp-data/777775555/5lc_payload0.pickle 5lc_payload0_s3.pickle
with open('5lc_payload0_s3.pickle', 'rb') as f: 
    pickle.load(f)
```

I get ‘EOFError: ran put of input’

When comparing both pickle files with 'cmp'
[image]

I have been doing many package version changes with no success so far. And the thing is that the above code works with python3.6 but not with python3.8

I am using pandas 1.4, boto3 1.17.28 and botocore 1.20.112

Comment: <https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/>

Comment: Fixed the image error

Comment: Does it work when you don't do the upload/download step and you just dump the file locally and then load it afterwards also locally? What does `ls -l` say on both files? What is the operating system of the machine that runs the Python code?

Comment: When reading the file before uploading it does work indeed. I am working on centos07 and the file is 48MB when I ‘ls-lth’

Comment: And without the `-h`? It is important to compare the _exact_ filesizes of the two files.

Comment: What do you think it could be the cause if they are different.

Comment: I don't know, that depends on what the difference is - the EOF suggests that the s3 version is cut off, knowing how many bytes are missing might give some clues on where the difference comes from.

Comment: Note that a workaround could be to zip the file before uploading it and unzipping after downloading it again, if the zip file is not also altered of course. But that would not tell you what the actual problem is.

Comment: Here is the difference in byes
Original 165264557 
S3 Upload 165264465

Comment: that is around 158MB, that is different than the 48MB you mentioned above? Anyway, it is a 92 bytes difference, it would be interesting to know if this difference occurs and the start or end of the file.

Comment: I took another pickle file that experienced the same error. 
How can I get that info at the begining or end of file ? ?

Comment: Check both with a hex viewer, for example `xxd` (pipe to less or head/tail to handle the long output).

Comment: I can see the difference is at the end of the last 10 lines